# Background Image Hover Transition Delay

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to avoid javascript to display image rollovers correctly, using the transition delay hack. It works for the divs with coloured thumbs, as it changes the main image and stays when you scroll the mouse off the thumb, but when you hover over the picture thumb, the main image doesn't stay when hovering over the thumb.

Any ideas why this happens? I've tried `transition: background-image 0s` but to no avail.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #eee;
}

#redL {
  background: red;
}

#greenL {
  background: green;
}

#blueL {
  background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486757.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

label {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

#redL:hover ~ #big {
  background: red;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

#greenL:hover ~ #big {
  background: green;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

#blueL:hover ~ #big {
  background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486757.jpg');
  /* background: blue; */
  transition: background-image 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

#big {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #fff;
  clear: both;
  margin: auto;
  transition: all .1s 604800s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <label id="redL"></label>
  <label id="greenL"></label>
  <label id="blueL"></label>
  
  <div id="big">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The rule Says : In order for a transition to happen the target property has to be already been set.**

Which is pretty straight forward, you can't make a transition happen if there's nothing to transition from, You're probably looking for animations.

Anyway

In your Case the `div#big` doesn't have a `background-image` so the transition, doesn't take place, therefore your hackie delay doesn't work since there's no transition to delay.

A work around is to set the `div#id` to an img by default, or a starting/placeholder img if you must.

And also you can't mix colors and imgs, because as the rule says you'll have to have the same property already set,background-color and background-image, override each other.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #eee;
}

#redL {
  background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486754.jpg');
}

#blueL {
  background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486757.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

label {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

#redL:hover ~ #big {
  background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486754.jpg');
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

#blueL:hover ~ #big {
  background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486757.jpg');
  /* background: blue; */
  transition-delay: 0s;
 
}

#big {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #fff;
  clear: both;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486756.jpg');
  transition: all .1s 604800s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <label id="redL"></label>
  <label id="blueL"></label>
  
  <div id="big">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question was, Any ideas why this happens? if the OP wants what you mentioned, then as i said in the answer, it's animations that he needs

Comment: wow, very well explained, thanks! One small question (I've made this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6dosnhok/) - I noticed that the main #big div cannot start with the same background image as the hover thumbs, otherwise the hover only works once for the same thumb image (hover over the fiddle images and you'll understand). Changing this #big bg image to another image works, but is there a workaround for using the same image as one of the small thumbs?

Comment: This seems odd, but it's straight forward, when you start with one of the imgs, and you hover on one of the thumbs, then you go o back to hover on the same img that you started with, this means nothing has changed, because by default you have the same one, so nothing happens, so the previous img transition  delay stays, your best bet here to use a placeholder-like img.

Comment: sorry, but I don't entirely understand, because it changes once but then never again. Is it something quick you could edit on this fiddle? jsfiddle.net/6dosnhok

Comment: You can't start with one of the thumbs imgs, because i'll be set by the default when you're not hovering anymore of any of them, the background changes back to the default one, but you don't see it, because the delay is too long, so when you hover back on the one you started with nothing changes, because it's the same Background

Comment: any idea why it won't work on this one? https://jsfiddle.net/62vw3kvw/ - it's the exact same principles! are hacks just dodgy and unreliable?

Comment: You may wanna take a look at this  - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp

Comment: ohh I see - it's not selecting the right element. But how on earth do you select the right element? I think the :hover is the confusing bit, because even on the working element in the other demo, I get how it uses ~  to select the element, but not apply the hover!